# __autoload() Doesn't seem to do anything in PHP

Tags: php, xampp, autoload

I'm running the latest version of XAMPP and autoload() doesn't seem to be working as it should. I pretty much replaced my previous autoload with the one from the PHP manual, but to no avail.

After putting a few echo's and die()s, I've concluded that __autoload isn't being invoked at all.

```
class Main
{

    var $config_data;

    function __autoload($class_name) {
        echo "hello.";
        // If the file exists, require it
        if (file_exists(SYSTEMDIR.$class_name.".".EXT)) {
            echo 'Autoloader: The class exists.';
            (require_once(SYSTEMDIR.$class_name.".".EXT))
                or die("I tried to autoload class $class_name, but it failed! =(");
        } else {
            // The file didn't even exist. Die.
            die("I was going to autoload class $class_name, but it didn't exist! =(");
        }

    }

    /*
     * Function __construct
     * @param datatype variable description
     * @return datatype description
     */
   function __construct(/* $arg */) {
       //Load the config

       $this->config = new Config;

       //Load the uri class:
       $this->uri = new Uri;
   }

}
```

It doesn't output the "hello" that is located at the very top of __autoload().

The only output is:

> Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found
>   in E:\xampplite\htdocs\system\Main.php
>   on line 84

Comment: can you put __autoload inside a class? you want to use autoload as a general function, dont you?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__autoload` doesn't go *in* the class. It's used to *include* the file the class is in.

You'll need to add an autoload **function** to the initial script to ever have it do anything.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that mentioned anywhere in the PHP manual! -.-

It also seems that I have to wait seven minutes to choose an answer...

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK function `__autoload` must be defined outside the class. If you want to implement autoload function as part of a class, you should use callback and [spl_autoload_register](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: This is also the prefered way, because other libraries may use own autoloaders. Two functions with the same name are not allowed and if someone registers an autoloader to `spl_autoload_register()` the `__autoload()`-function gets not called anymore.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you declared a `Main->__autoload()` function (i.e. a class method) not a global `__autoload()`